# How would I create a single landing page so that it displays custom information based off of an agents generated "6-digit code"

Tags: php, mysql

Long-winded question here but basically I need to make a single landing page customized specifically for each agent (I'll be getting a list of like 100 agents).  So obviously instead of creating a landing page for each agent it would be best if I could have information swap in based on their personal 6-digit code that I'll generate and have them plug in.  Could I use an excel file plus the database and somehow switch out the variable text and images?  Is this something that's even possible?  My php/mysql knowledge is pretty limited at the moment but if you have any resources on this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You would store the information for each agent in a mysql database and use php to generate a custom or dynamic page.  You just need to google some php tutorials to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way (assuming that you are using just `pure php and mysql`):

Suppose you have the database table `agent` which has various information about each of the agents stored as table rows. For example:

Table `agent`:

---

`id`

`first_name`

`last_name`

`country`

---

Then you can write a php function, lets say `get_agent_details($agent_id)` that will fetch the corresponding record from the mysql database.

```
function get_agent_details($agent_id)
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_username","mysql_pwd");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    // Now run your query
    $agent_data = "SELECT * FROM agent where id=" . $agent_id;
    mysql_query($agent_data,$con);
    mysql_close($con);
    return $agent_data;
}
```

Now you can display this data as you please in your page. Please note that I am just giving you a skeleton code that might give you ideas for suitable implementation. *This is not production ready code.*

Comment: Hopefully this has solved your question. If not please let me know. If yes, then I'd appreciate it if you can accept the answer :)